# Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3 error while launching in Mac with os x

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Hi I am getting this error, while launching the studio in Mac OSX after extracting from the zip(downloaded from official website),

Error Log:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b8d7286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8daae9ab abort + 129
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104ba7d7b os::abort(bool) + 25
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104cc8676 VMError::report_and_die() + 2304
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104ba99de JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104ba5c0b signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff891f2f1a _sigtramp + 26
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8da51f92 strlen + 18
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ea29a3c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8524
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eb1f3a0 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 256
```

How to solve this?

Edit : I am using java version "1.8.0_51".

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this advice?

Due to a bug, you can only patch from Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 to Preview 3. All other users  will need to download a complete install of the IDE. With Android Studio 2.2, you may have noticed the larger download sizes than previous versions of Android Studio; this is because we now bundle a build of OpenJDK with the IDE to address various font rendering and stability issues.

Source:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-preview-3

Comment: Yep, I downloaded from the same link. I even tried downloading 2.2 Preview 2 and updated to Preview 3, but same error repeats after launching the studio..